# Java Spark - how to generate structType from a json object

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, avro

How do i create a struct type out of a JSON object in java? The JSON object in my case is an AVRO schema(i have truncated it below).

```
{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"DataRecord\",\"namespace\":\"com.mycode\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"data\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Data\",
\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"COUNT\",\"type\":[{\"type\":\"null\"},{\"type\":\"int\"}],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"VALUE\",\"type\":[{\"type\":\"null\"},{\"type\":\"int\"}],\"default\":null}] }
```

I prefer not to manually create the StructType object. I have seen ways to do it Scala, but nothing similar in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.5"`  , `"com.databricks" %% "spark-avro" % "3.2.0"`

I was able to convert Json String Schema to AVRO Schema then to Struct Type.

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import com.databricks.spark.avro.SchemaConverters;


String schemaStr ="{ \"type\" : \"record\", \"name\" : \"test_schema\", \"namespace\" : \"com.test.avro\", \"fields\" : [ { \"name\" : \"username\", \"type\" : \"string\", \"doc\"  : \"blah blah\" }, { \"name\" : \"tweet\", \"type\" : \"string\", \"doc\"  : \"test\" }, { \"name\" : \"timestamp\", \"type\" : \"long\", \"doc\"  : \"test\" } ], \"doc:\" : \"test\" }";
Schema schema = Schema.parse(schemaStr);    
StructType requiredType = (StructType) SchemaConverters.toSqlType(schema).dataType();
```

Note : The newer versions of Spark / Scala have included `"com.databricks" %% "spark-avro"` by default

Comment: Thanks for that, can i please ask you how could I then store a corresponding json data object with this structure in a DataFrame? i.e. I have data in the format of the schema, and i want to store it in a dataframe such that each property is a column?

Comment: you can do it by `val df = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, requiredType)`

Comment: but what about in Java?

Comment: @GMan
just check `java` tab on https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema